# Spring Boot web app without maven

Tags: spring-boot, jar

Friends,

I am trying to build a Spring boot project. but the challenge is maven isn't working in office environment(basically proxy isn't allowing).

Is there any way to create a spring boot project without maven?

if I can get any boiler code link would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just add all the necessary jar in project class path manually. Example Spring boot project jar added by gradle. 
    [Part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPIfl.png)
    [Part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53tFp.png)